# Using Jquery for for an ajax uploader running into document error on trigger

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form that I am using jquery form to upload files with ajax.

The problem I am having is this.

the url the form is on is http://admin.kaalaphp.com?cmd=cXVKd29jMnlwYW1WajZ1anlKWFIzJTJCR2xyWkt6dEglMkJWbEt1cHNhRFYydGFvbCUyQkJxcTdTZ21hWnlobGJNejY5aw%3D%3D

but the ajax call is to http://kaalaphp.com/ajax_processes/uploadImages.php

when the upload is triggered the following javascript error is generated.

```
[jquery.form] Server abort: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' (Error)
```

This is related to cross domain ajax calls, I am wondering if there is a quick fix to allow this to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
crossDomain: true
};
// pass options to ajaxForm
$("#upload_images").ajaxForm(options);
$("#upload_images").on('change', '#media_images', function(){
$("#ajaxUploader").html("");
$("#ajaxUploader").html('<img src="http://kaalaphp.com/images/loading.gif" alt="Uploading...."/> Uploading....');
$("#upload_images").ajaxForm({
target: "#ajaxUploader"
}).submit();
});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: have you done anything about configuring the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on `kaalaphp.com`? (going to assume that page isn't supposed to 404?)

Comment: Sorry my bad the link was wrong I have corrected it.

Comment: I have not done any Access-Control-Allow-Origin info on the domain. 

Will that allow the ajax uploader to function? How should I set it up?

Never worked with it before

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your `uploadImages.php` file

As a whitelist...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://admin.kaalaphp.com, http://kaalaphp.com');
```

or alternatively...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Place this code before any headers are sent

Comment: still get the error [jquery.form] Server abort: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' (Error)  the error is being generated by jquery.form.js

Comment: And that's with the wildcard `*` header as well? If not, I think we're going to need to see more code of your form/jquery setup.

Comment: Yah I tried both neither worked. I have posted the javascript function.